# Currency symbol gets lost on specific store view

Tags: store-view

I got two store views in my shop.

1 english and 1 arabic(ar_SA)

Standard currency is SAR

On english store view the shop shows me SAR 100.00 for example.
On arabic store view I just get the Number itself like 100.00.

Can someone tell me why the SAR is missing?

EDIT:
Found out that in arabic store view the custom currency symbol is NOT used.
Tested it by hard coding symbol in app/code/core/Mage/CurrencySymbol/Model/System/Currencysymbol.php (just for test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure whats going wrong here but following fixed it for me:

`lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml`

removed:

```
<numbers>
        <decimalFormats>
            <decimalFormatLength>
                <decimalFormat>
                    <pattern>#0.###;#0.###-</pattern>
                </decimalFormat>
            </decimalFormatLength>
        </decimalFormats>
        <currencyFormats>
            <currencyFormatLength>
                <currencyFormat>
                    <pattern>¤#0.00</pattern>
                </currencyFormat>
            </currencyFormatLength>
        </currencyFormats>
</numbers>
```

Comment: Good to know that it is fixed

Comment: always a good things to find the answer by yourself. If you find it being the most suitable answer to your question, please accept it.

Comment: This solution not working for me in Magento ver. 1.9.2.4. Can someone tell me how i can  fix it ?

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Go To

> System>Manage Currency>Symbols

, and add symbols there.

Comment: did that already

Comment: I hope locale/timezones etc.. are also changed

Comment: yeah that changed, but just found out thats the problem. if i use Saudi local the symbol gets lost. When i use US its visible.... strange ^^

Comment: Check if this helps you any where:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281131/how-do-i-change-the-currency-symbol-in-magento-1-5-1-0