# The currency symbol ($) is missing when changing the store view to Arabic Language

Tags: magento-1.9, price, currency, language

The currency symbol (`$`) is missing when changing the store view to Arabic Language.

I got two store views in my shop.

1 **english** and 1 **arabic**(ar_SA)

Standard currency is `$` in all my shop.

On english store view the shop shows me `$` 100.00 for example. On arabic store view I just get the Number itself like 100.00.

**Can someone tell me why the `$` is missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Problem is **solved**.

**`Solution:`**

**in** `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml`

Must be **removed** the below code:

```
<numbers>
        <decimalFormats>
            <decimalFormatLength>
                <decimalFormat>
                    <pattern>#0.###;#0.###-</pattern>
                </decimalFormat>
            </decimalFormatLength>
        </decimalFormats>
        <currencyFormats>
            <currencyFormatLength>
                <currencyFormat>
                    <pattern>¤#0.00</pattern>
                </currencyFormat>
            </currencyFormatLength>
        </currencyFormats>
</numbers>
```

or this if exist

```
<numbers>
    <currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
        <currencyFormatLength>
            <currencyFormat type="standard">
                <pattern>¤#0.00</pattern>
            </currencyFormat>
        </currencyFormatLength>
    </currencyFormats>
</numbers>
```

**Reference:** [Currency symbol gets lost on specific store view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24047/currency-symbol-gets-lost-on-specific-store-view)

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :)

Answer (score -1):

Probably your its about your currency setup.

1-In admin panel, go to Admin > System > Configuration > Currency Set up.

2-Select currency that you want to be default from your base currency drop down.

3-Select the same currency in the Default Display Currency drop down and from the Allowed Currencies list.

4-Save

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem it applied previously , i want another solution for my problem.